# Same Query through PHP and PHPMyAdmin gives different results?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Sorry for my English mistakes. I've tried to look on the internet for a solution to this but I wasn't able to.

I have this query `"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT idu) FROM utente NATURAL JOIN bicicletta WHERE modello = '$modello'"`

`$modello` is a parameter coming from the DB, which was inserted by the user in a different page. Now when the parameter is a normal string, the query works fine in both PHP and PHPMyAdmin, but when the string has a `'` character the PHP Query always returns 0 no matter what.

The query in particular that has been giving me problem is this one:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT idu)
FROM utente NATURAL JOIN bicicletta
WHERE modello = '<b>Cho\'Gath</b>'
```

This returns `3` in PHPMyAdmin and `0` in PHP.

This is the full code

```
$modello = mysqli_real_escape_string($cid, $row[2]);

$model = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT idu) FROM utente NATURAL JOIN bicicletta 
    WHERE modello = '$modello'";
$modelres = $cid->query($model)
    or die("Impossibile eseguire query. <br> Codice errore ". $cid->errno .": ". $cid->error ."<br>");
$model = $modelres->fetch_row()[0];
```

My guess is there's gotta be some problem with the interaction between the `mysqli_real_escape_string` function and the following query but I haven't been able to find any.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: why are you escaping your own db? You escape before it goes in db, not while it's in there.

Comment: Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly on what's already in db? *lol*

Comment: What is the query supposed to do anyway!?!?!

Comment: Have you tried dumping `$model` before you execute it to see if it's really the same thing?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have to otherwise I have syntax error since the parameter has a ' in it

Comment: Try `addslashes()` or `stripslashes()` then.

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes I did, I echoed $model and copy pasted it in PHPMyAdmin and gave me the desired result, while $model after the fetch_row gives me 0

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've been thinking about it but I did the whole project using the old method and wanted to see if I could continue doing it the same way. Thanks for the tip though

Comment: @Strawberry Basically counting how many users has that particular model of bike. The query works in PHPMyAdmin but for some reason it always returns 0 in the code, so that must be something with syntax and not semantics ^^ I didn't explain the whole thing since I didn't want to make it too long

Comment: I just found out that the problem is with the HTMLEntity <b> and not with the ' character since Cho'Gath works but <b>ChoGath</b> returns 0 ! That was surprising to me

Comment: I just resolved the problem! It was me calling the htmlentities php function on $row[2]; just moving it after the $row[2] called in the query fixed it. Thanks to everyone for the help!